# Defining a variable as part of a function

Tags: php, function, variables

Im having trouble setting a variable as part of a function, im sure its down the syntax more than anything, what im trying to do is use a if/else statement and as part of it, to  return a variable $Bname.

But im not sure how to set it.

My function is as follows

```
 function bestPriceFunc($var1, $var2) {
      if ($var1 < $var2) {
          return $var1;
          $Bname = 'will';
          return $Bname;

      } else {
          return $var2;
          $Bname = 'Lad';
          return $Bname;
      }
  }
```

is this the correct way to do it or could i just write `return $Bname = 'Lad';`. Ive tried both but i getting an undefined variable error when i load the page

Comment: `$Bname = ...;` and `return $Bname;` are never executed because you have `return $varX;` just before these two statements. `return` **terminates** the function. Apart from that I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use return once per function as it terminates the function the first time it is executed.

Try the following or if you don't need to return $var1 and $var2, simply remove those lines.

```
<?php
function bestPriceFunc($var1, $var2) {
    if ($var1 < $var2) {
        $Bname = 'will';
        return array($var1, $Bname);

    } else {
        $Bname = 'Lad';
        return array($var2, $Bname);
    }
}

$var = bestPriceFunc(3, 4);
$bnameoutput = $var[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined errors when you attempt to use the `$Bname` variable because you are already returning `$var1` and `$var2`.

A return statement ends the function.  Once you hit `return $var1;` or `return $var2` the function ends and returns the specified variable.  In order to return the `$Bname` variable, you need to get rid of the other returns.

Answer (score 0):

Once you return `$var;` the function execution ends, meaning that the rest of the code is ignored, so `$Bname` is not set.

You also have two "return" in each function, I suggest having a lopk at how functions work